# Standard way of referencing an object by identity (for, eg, circular references)?

Tags: json

Is there a standard way of referencing objects by identity in JSON? For example, so that graphs and other data structures with lots of (possibly circular) references can be sanely serialized/loaded?

**Edit**: I know that it's easy to do one-off solutions (“make a list of all the nodes in the graph, then …”). I'm wondering if there is a standard, generic, solution to this problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was searching on this same feature recently. There does not seem to be a standard or ubiquitous implementation for referencing in JSON. I found a couple of resources that I can share:

- **The Future for JSON Referencing**

http://groups.google.com/group/json-schema/browse_thread/thread/95fb4006f1f92a40 - This is just a discussion on id-based referencing.

- **JSON Referencing in Dojo**

http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/17/json-referencing-in-dojo/ - An implementation in Dojox (extensions for the Dojo framework) - discusses id-based and path based referencing.

- **JSONPath - XPath for JSON**

http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/ - This seems to be an attempt at establishing a standard for path based JSON referencing - maybe a small subset of XPath (?). There seems to be an implementation here but I kept getting errors on the download section - you might have better luck. But again this is no where close to a standard yet.

Answer (score 10):

There is the ["JSON Reference" specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03), but it seems it didn't got over the state of an expired Internet draft.

Still, it seems to be used in [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) and [Swagger](http://swagger.io/specification/#referenceObject) (now OpenAPI) (for reusing parts of an API description in other places of the same or another API description).

A reference to an object in the same file looks like this: `{ "$ref": "#/definitions/Problem" }`.

Comment: The JSON Pointer draft became [a RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6901) though

Comment: I believe this response confuses references to subschema definition in JSON schema with references to data objects. $ref is part of the schema definition and not part of the data structure referring instances defined elsewhere in the JSON...

Comment: @user14216064 The JSON (or swagger) schema definition itself is a JSON document. And it's using the functionality provided for JSON documents by "JSON reference". I agree that I've not seen it used elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Douglas Crockford has a solution that uses JSONPath (an Xpath-like syntax for describing json paths). It seems fairly sane:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js

Answer (score 1):

There is no canonical way to achieve that. JSON does not have a native support for references, so you have to invent your own scheme for unique identifiers which will act as pointers. If you really want to make it generic you could use the object identifiers provided by your programming language (eg. `object_id` in Ruby or `id(obj)` in Python).