# Can I somehow save circular data structures with JSON or something similar?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, error-handling, reference

When trying to save some data about the game world in a file using JSON, I get that good ol' JSON circular reference error. Is there a way to save circular data types? Also, I'm running this with node.js, not inside a browser.

Basically, over time, the player gets some units. These units are saved to a list inside the player object, but are given the player himself as an argument, so they know who's their owner. Something like this:

```
Player = function()
{
    this.power = 0
    this.units = [new Unit(this)];
}

Unit = function(owner)
{
    owner.power++;   
}
```

Comment: You can't serialize a circular reference, can you maybe reference an id instead?

Comment: There are serialisation libraries that solve this problem for you: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to save an object with circular references?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420597/javascript-how-to-save-an-object-with-circular-references)

Comment: Hey, that cycle.js file seems to be what I need, but how do I include it in my code?

Comment: Hey, editing that code is way out of my league, I don't get half of the syntax and it's hard to read... Would you care to give me some tips on where to put the "exports" prefix please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bane, in answer to how to include the cycle.js

Put it in your lib folder for your project and include it via a script tag if you're doing it on the client side.

On the server side you could include the code in the file that you need the circular reference in; that's simple but really the wrong way to work. Better bet is to build it out as a module, check [this tutorial on howtonode.org](http://howtonode.org/creating-custom-modules) for the specifics.

Your overall best bet though is to refactor so that you don't need the circular reference.

Comment: So, the basic idea is that I have to edit the cycle.js file, adding the "export" prefix to those two functions?

Comment: Mostly, I didn't check the cycle.js file thoroughly so I'm not 100% sure if it depends on anything else. But otherwise, yeah basically. Also, it uses jsonPath so you'll want to npm install jsonpath [here's the git](https://github.com/temsa/jsonpath) Looks like it would work after that.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'm gonna give it a try tomorrow and get you back. I'm having some troubles with positioning system, so I just commented out the part where it saves the game, gonna deal with it later.