# Handling JavaScript events in WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to catch every `onClick` event in `WKWebView`. 
The website is working only with JavaScript so I cannot handle anything in:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

you can use a WKUserScript and add it to the userContentController of the WKWebView's configuration.

```
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let source = "document.addEventListener('click', function(){ window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosListener.postMessage('click clack!'); })"
    let script = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)
    config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
    config.userContentController.add(self, name: "iosListener")
    webView = WKWebView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds, configuration: config)
```

this will make the script and inject it into the page when the document is finished loading. Now, you need to implement the WKScriptMessageHandler protocol to receive the message:

```
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print("message: \(message.body)")
        // and whatever other actions you want to take
    }
```

Comment: Gosh, I wasted so much time to have this working! Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RedRoosterMobile, this concept is also working on Android. Check addJavascriptInterface method on android.webkit.WebView

Comment: @ɯɐɹʞ could you plz let me know what reference you are passing as 'self' in line:     config.userContentController.add(self, name: "iosListener")

Comment: @iMRahib, self is the controller that is presenting the webview

Answer (score 9):

If you want to add click listener only for button with id 'buttonX' (`<button id="buttonX">Click me</button>`) then

```
let scriptSource = """
var button = document.getElementById('buttonX');
document.body.style.backgroundColor = `red`;
if(button != null) {
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosClickListener.postMessage('open_invitation');
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = `green`;
    });
}

"""

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptSource, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)

        config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
        config.userContentController.add(self, name: "iosClickListener")


        let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: config)

        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil) //load your html body here

    }

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if let body = message.body as? String, body == "open_invitation" {
            print("✅ we did it")
        }
    }
```

Also your view controller should conform to `WKScriptMessageHandler` protocol

Answer (score -3):

You can use the WebViewJavascriptBridge. Please refer the below link for details :

https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge

Comment: Why would I want to add a 3rd party library that ads to my app bundle of which continued development is uncertain, while WKWebView supports already everything with an Objective-C style interface?