# How to add observer to play and pause actions for audio file in WKWebview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview, avaudiofile

I want to add notifications for play and pause actions of audio file in wkwebview, 
Image shows how audio files are in WKWebview

[image]

Comment: You can catch JS functions for the buttons in webView, if you want to use them. What kind of notifications do you want to add

Comment: @Adarsh I just want to stop and resume video recorder which not part of WKWebview, when user play and pause audio files respectively

Comment: and video recorder is in the web view only or native?

Comment: @Adarsh Video recorder is native and its using AVCaptureAudioDataOutput.

Comment: As I mentioned above you can use the JS functions in wkwebview and with those you can send the data also so that should help you call a native function and handle it as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, I will just put it down here as an answer. The `WkWebview` can handle the JS functions being used in the elements of the `webView` to handle those messages as per your requirement.
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/45063303/6727332
This is the link where you can find how to implement the same.