# How to listen web page postMessage event in WKWebview?

Tags: javascript, swift, wkwebview, safari-app-extension

I make my WKWebview load a web page like this:

```swift
class SafariExtensionViewController: SFSafariExtensionViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    static let shared = SafariExtensionViewController()
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        self.preferredContentSize = NSMakeSize(400, 600)
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myURL = URL(string: frameUrl)
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
        os_log("EXTEST the WKWebview has loaded")
    }

}
```

and in my localhost web service js file, I add a post message event

```js
window.parent.postMessage(message, '*')
```

Now I try to listen to this event in my swift code, is it posssible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45063303/6727332 Check this answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling JavaScript events in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062929/handling-javascript-events-in-wkwebview)

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/LXVimeoKit

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to react to JavaScript callbacks. Check `WKWebView`s `evaluateJavaScript:` method.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript