# How to detect if video is running in PiP mode inside WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, picture-in-picture

I have a WKWebView which allows to enable PiP mode on videos.

The problem is that when the user "closes" the WKWebView, I have to call `wkWebView.pauseAllMediaPlayback()`, otherwise the sound keeps playing in the system even if I unload the WKWebView with `= nil`.

This works great, but if PiP is enabled I want to keep the WKWebView alive and do not call the stop media playback method.

So is there a way to detect if PiP is opened?

I thought of attaching a delegate to the player inside WKWebView, but I'm not allowed to do that:

[image: player inside WKWebView]

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't seem possible from Swift side, I managed to detect PiP via Javascript.

You have to listen to PiP enter/leave events triggered by videos in Javascript, then call your own code via a Javascript Bridge.

[Please see this answer on how to do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45063303/4054061)

Then you have to change the Javascript code to look like this:

```
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
        for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
            videos[i].addEventListener('enterpictureinpicture', () => window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosListener.postMessage('enterpictureinpicture'), false);
            videos[i].addEventListener('leavepictureinpicture', () => window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosListener.postMessage('leavepictureinpicture'));
        }
    });
```

This is calling your Swift code passing `enterpictureinpicture` or `leavepictureinpicture` as a message.