# When i try to log mouse event i get lots of output but try to send to server it's a blank object?

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript to send my server the entire 'mousemove' event. I can log the event but as soon as it reaches my server it just shows up as

```
{}
```

my code:

```
var socket = io();

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(ev){
    console.log(ev);
    socket.emit('mousemove', ev);
}, true, true);
```

any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about `console.log(JSON.stringify(ev));`?

Comment: The only output I get is `{"isTrusted": true}`

Comment: It is definitely not a mousemove event

Comment: I get exactly what I want when I use `console.log(ev)` i it just turn to a blank object once i try to send it

Comment: @DavidDiefenderfer That's because you can't send objects over the wire. Only strings. (That's why most people use JSON)

Comment: But `socket.emit('mousemove', {mouse: 'moved', object: 'is working'});` works fine

Comment: @DavidDiefenderfer so what have `console.log(JSON.stringify(ev));` exactly output?

Comment: `{"isTrusted": true}` is actually the first property of the event object, so perhaps you have an issue on the server-side?

Comment: when I stringify the object I literally just get `{"isTrusted": true}`

Comment: I thought so as well but that happens when I stringify in client

Comment: Seems like serialisation algorithms (both JSON.serialise and socketio's) fail to serialise the object since it has references to DOM elements and circular references.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547672/how-to-stringify-event-object