# Javascript Object: Chrome debugger shows field/property exists, Can't access it through Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, javascript-debugger

I am having the strangest problem with javascript objects. I have a function that is an event handler that looks like this:

```
.on(some-event, function(event){
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.bytesLoaded);
    console.log(event.duration);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
})
```

The chrome debuggger shows the first line as this:

```
bytesLoaded:4575118
bytesTotal:4575118
delayLoadingTime:1503675333159
duration:4.004
```

The second line as:

```
NaN
```

The third line as:

```
4.004
```

And the fourth line as:

```
{"bytesLoaded":null,"bytesTotal":null,"delayLoadingTime":1503675822834,"duration":4.004}
```

Does anybody know why this strange behavior is happening? Is the chrome debugger lying about seeing an actual number in that field? The duration field works fine in both the debugger and being accessed through javascript.

Comment: Looks like your using jQuery, see what `console.log(event.originalEvent.bytesLoaded);` gives you

Comment: try logging `event.bytesLoaded.toString()` and see what happens

Comment: That is some very strange behavior but you don't want to do JSON.stringify on the event object. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547672/how-to-stringify-event-object) explains a lot more about it. Most likely what you want to do is just get the attributes off the event that you care about, put them in a new object and then serialize that object.

Comment: @JoeLissner console.log(event.originalEvent); gives undefined

Comment: @AminJafari console.log(event.bytesLoaded.toString()) gives NaN

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).