# How can I stringify a touchevent, ignoring any DOM references?

Tags: javascript, dom, serialization, touch-event

I'm using UniWebView as a UI for Unity.  I need to send touchevents to modify a 3D asset.  Uniwebview's messaging is done via URL format and thus has to be strings.

When I try to send a touchevent with `JSON.stringify()` it only sends `{isTrusted: true}`.  I have gone through everything in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547672/how-to-stringify-event-object) without luck.  The functions in the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34519193/736893) and [third](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24161582/736893) answers return the same result, only the `isTrusted` object.

In the top answer, the author explicitly stated you should not delete all the DOM references, but in my use-case I think it's completely acceptable.

How can I do that?

It would be nice if it did it automagically (detecting if it was a DOM element  ("circular references")) but I think I could also manually filter the following keys:

- changedTouches[x].target
- currentTarget
- path[]
- srcElement
- target
- targetTouches[x].target
- touches[x].target
- view

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549320/looping-through-an-object-tree-recursively) for looping through an object recursively, but the comments imply that circular references may cause an overflow.  On top of that, I'm not sure how I would "rebuild" the object.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Not a solution, but temporarily I am just retrieving the touches:

```
function getTouches(e) {
    let touches = e.touches;
    let output = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < touches.length; i++) {
        let touch = {
            clientX: touches[i].clientX,
            clientY: touches[i].clientY
        };
        output.push(touch);
    }
    return output;
}
```