# Stringifying event object works, but is practically empty

Tags: javascript, json, dom

I have this custom stringify function which can handle circular references:

```
const customStringify = function (v) {
  return JSON.stringify(v, function(k, v) {
    if (v instanceof Node) {
      return 'Node';
    }
    if (v instanceof Window) {
      return 'Window';
    }
    return v;
  });
};
```

but if I use it to stringify an event object:

```
  window.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {   // MouseEvent
    const v = customStringify(ev);  // {"isTrusted":true}
  });
```

v is just string that looks like this:

```
{"isTrusted":true}
```

so bizarre. I tried a few other custom stringifying helper functions, and they all give me the same result.

I looked at this thread:
[How to stringify event object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547672/how-to-stringify-event-object)

but my problem seems more specific.

Comment: I also looked to see if the MouseEvent has a `toJSON` method somewhere in the prototype chain, and I didn't see one

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by doing this? Or are you just curious?

Comment: my goal is to pass event data between threads on the front-end (message passing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) ignores non-enumerable properties, and most of the properties of a [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) are (apparently) non-enumerable:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', ev => {
  let props = ['isTrusted', 'target', 'clientX', 'clientY', 'layerX', 'layerY'];
  props.forEach(prop => {
    console.log(prop + '?', ev.propertyIsEnumerable(prop));
  });
});
```

```html
<button>Try it!</button>
```

You can call each property out by name and make it enumerable before handing the event off to `JSON.stringify`:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', ev => {
  let props = ['target', 'clientX', 'clientY', 'layerX', 'layerY'];
  props.forEach(prop => {
    Object.defineProperty(ev, prop, {
      value: ev[prop],
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    });
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(ev));
});
```

```html
<button>Try it again!</button>
```