# Can you store circular objects in a session?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I'm using Blocktrail's API, in order to manage bitcoin wallets. The API returns a wallet object, which I guess has circular references contained within.

I want to store the decrypted wallet in the user's session, so that the user doesn't have to enter their password again, but whenever I try to do something like this (`wallet` being the wallet object returned by the API):

```
req.session.wallet = wallet;
```

I get:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at MemoryStore.set
```

So, if an object has a circular structure, is there a way to store a reference to it in a session? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serialize circular structure into JSON string, so you can't store it in session.

You would have to strip all the circular references before serializing to JSON string.

Comment: So I guess that the sessions' implementation tries to stringify the object, since sessions store strings, right? But wouldn't stripping out circular references interfere with the object's functionality? Isn't there a way to keep the object intact and make it persist the session?

Comment: As per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420597/javascript-how-to-save-an-object-with-circular-references, check out [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). Supposedly it can store circular JSON using JSONPath.