# Handling reference loops in JSON.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I wish to serialize a collection (`List<Item>`) of items to JSON.

These items have a collection of `Connection` which gives information about the connection from one `Item` to a second `Item`. And since the connection object has a reference to the items it makes it an infinite loop.

**My question is is there a way for me to skip serialization of the connection collection when serializing the object the second time.**

I've tried things like inheriting from `JsonConverter` and writing a custom `WriteJson()` method but from there I have no sence whether I should write out the array or not.

I've also tried using a custom ContractResolver but with no good results.

**Classes**

```
public class Item
{
    private static int _lastID = 0;

    public Item()
    {
        ID = ++_lastID;
        Connections = new List<Connection>();
    }


    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public List<Connection> Connections { get; set; }

}



public class Connection
{
    private Connection(ConnectionType type, Item source, Item target)
    {
        if (type == ConnectionType.None)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (target == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("target");

        Type = type;
        Source = source;
        Target = target;
    }


    public ConnectionType Type { get; set; }

    public Item Source { get; set; }

    public Item Target { get; set; }


    public static void Connect(ConnectionType type, Item source, Item target)
    {
        var conn = new Connection(type, source, target);
        source.Connections.Add(conn);
        target.Connections.Add(conn);
    }
}
```

**Wanted result:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Item #1",
        "prop1": "val1",
        "prop2": "val2",
        "connections": {
            "type": "ConnType",
            "source": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Item #1",
                "prop1": "val1",
                "prop2": "val2"
                // no connections array
            },
            "target": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Item #2",
                "prop1": "val1",
                "prop2": "val2"
                // no connections array
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Item #2",
        "prop1": "val1",
        "prop2": "val2",
        "connections": {
            "type": "ConnType",
            "source": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Item #1",
                "prop1": "val1",
                "prop2": "val2"
                // no connections array
            },
            "target": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Item #2",
                "prop1": "val1",
                "prop2": "val2"
                // no connections array
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**EDIT:**

**C#**

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    };
settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collection, settings);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of declaring the type of `Source` and `Target` as of `Item`, you may introduce a new class, say, `ItemClass`, which'll contain all the fields of class `Item`, except the `Connections` property.

```
public class ItemClass
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class Connection
{
    // ...

    public ConnectionType Type { get; set; }

    public ItemClass Source { get; set; }

    public ItemClass Target { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Now you'll have an overhead of populating the new `ItemClass` type instance accordingly.

Comment: I like this solution but as it introduces more complexity I going with @Moeri solution

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your Global.asax (or in the WebApiConfig or any other config class)

```
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Comment: If've tried mixing with the `ReferenceLoopHandling` before with no luck, but now when I tried it again it gave me exactly what I wanted.

Thank you for pointing me back in the right direction. Although I use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collection, settings);`

Comment: Now I remembered why it didn't work with `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`. The connection object only has one reference either the source or the target depending from which object it was serializing. This doens't work for me, so I'll end up with @Wasif's solution after all

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you need to keep only the first depth of reference containing the connection collection? If that is the case, try using:

```
settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
settings.MaxDepth = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue, since objects can't be referenced in Json (see [Standard way of referencing an object by identity (for, eg, circular references)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001474/json-standard-way-of-referencing-an-object-by-identity-for-eg-circular-refer)).

This means you have to duplicate an item for each time it occurs in a reference to bring all the connections to the client.

I suggest to bring the connections to the client using only ids, with the connections as a seperate object.

Add the `JsonIgnore` attribute to the `Connections` property on the `Item`.

```
[JsonIgnore]
public List<Connection> Connections { get; set; }
```

And use a class to send to the client instead of the list of items directly.

```
    class ConnectionContainer
    {
        private readonly List<Item> _items;
        private readonly List<ConnectionInfo> _connections;

        public ConnectionContainer(IEnumerable<Item> items)
        {
            _items = items.ToList();
            Connections = items.SelectMany(i => i.Connections).Distinct().Select(c => new ConnectionInfo
            {
                Type = c.Type,
                SourceId = c.Source.ID,
                TargetId = c.Target.ID
            }).ToList();
        }

        public List<Item> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
        }

        public List<ConnectionInfo> Connections
        {
            get { return _connections; }
        }
    }

    class ConnectionInfo
    {
        private ConnectionType Type { get; set; }
        private int SourceId { get; set; }
        private int TargetId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: If I use this attribute I would loose all connection info, and I would prefer it to have the info only on the first object

Comment: As the classes are in a seperate project I want to avoid having to reference Newtonsoft.