# Json.NET configure serializer to reuse object instance for equal tokens

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have an invoice with two lines. On both lines I have the same product item selected. Now I want to deserialize this with Json.NET (former Newtonsoft.Json):

```
{
   "invoiceNumber":"SALES-001",
   "lines":[
      {
         "itemId":1,
         "lineDescription":"product with discount",
         "quantity":1,
         "price":1000,
         "item":{
            "id":1,
            "description":"product",
            "salesPrice":1200
         }
      },
      {
         "itemId":1,
         "lineDescription":"product",
         "quantity":1,
         "price":1200,
         "item":{
            "id":1,
            "description":"product",
            "salesPrice":1200
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

When deserializing this to C# objects I believe for each item a new instance is created, somewhat like:

```
new Item { Id = 1, Description = "product", SalesPrice = 1200 }
```

But what I actually want is that in the deserialization process the object instance for item, created on the first line, will be reused on the second line (by means of object comparison?).

Reading the docs I haven't found it. And going through the code I saw `JsonSerializerSettings` offers `ObjectCreationHandling.Reuse` and `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`. Only this does not seem to have the desired effect. So I've come to think that this is not possible by configuration.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: So do you need a Collection containing only distinct objects?

Comment: Maybe I have to rephrase some, but what I want is that both lines refere to the same item instance. So that only one item is instantiated

Comment: So you could parse the Json and then run Disctinct or DistinctBy over the Collection

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But if I understand correctly, this means I should rebuild the graph because after deserializing I want to pass the object along N-tiers. Also doing the equality comparison before serializing it to an object seems to me more efficient. Last but not least, I'm looking for a more generic approach that would achive this for any incomming JSON containing duplicate tokens.. Maybe I should update my question ;p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON: Standard way of referencing an object by identity (for, eg, circular references)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001474/json-standard-way-of-referencing-an-object-by-identity-for-eg-circular-refer)

Comment: No, as my question is specifically for deserializing with Json.NET

Comment: Json.NET supports [object references](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/preserveobjectreferences.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for Json.NET you can achieve this. But the JSON graph must be changed in order to make it work.

I couldn't find a standard where this behaviour is described. Json.NET seems to reuses the object instance if you change your JSON to:

```
{
    "$id":1,
    "invoiceNumber":"SALES-001",
    "lines":[
        {
            "$id":2,
            "itemId":1,
            "lineDescription":"product with discount",
            "quantity":1,
            "price":1000,
            "item":{
                "$id":3,
                "id":1,
                "description":"product",
                "salesPrice":1200
            }
        },
        {
            "$id":4,
            "itemId":1,
            "lineDescription":"product",
            "quantity":1,
            "price":1200,
            "item":{
                "$ref":3
             }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here you can see every object gets an unique `"$id"` assigned. The first `item` gets `"$id": 3` and the second `item` in the graph references to this `"$ref": 3`

I've found a project that handles the transformation of your JavaScript object: https://bitbucket.org/smithkl42/jsonnetdecycle

Quote from the project:

> JsonNetDecycle
>
> This is a very simple TypeScript/JavaScript library that can be used
> to re-establish object references removed by Json.NET. It's based on
> the cycle.js library by Douglas Crockford, but uses the non-standard
> reference style used by Json.NET instead of the IETF draft proposal
> for [JSON references](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03). Before you ask, yes, it would probably be better
> if Json.NET adopted the IETF proposed standard. But some of us need to
> get work done before that is likely to happen.
>
> You use it kinda like this:

```
var room = {
    "$id": "57",
    "Name": "_default",
    "User": {
        "$id": "58",
        "UserTag": "ken",
        "Sessions": [{
            "$id": "59",
            "SessionId": "0ca7474e-273c-4eb2-a0c1-1eba2f1a711c",
            "User": {
                "$ref": "58"
            },
            "Room": {
                "$ref": "57"
            }
        }],
    },

    "Sessions": [{
        "$ref": "59"
    }]
};
JsonNetDecycle.retrocycle(room);
alert(room.Sessions[0].User.UserTag);
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer. You talk about a new property but you don't explain how you use this or why you need it very well. Basically you seem to be saying the answer is add this new property, but I fail to see how adding a new property into a javascript object builds object references?

Comment: Right, so, TL;DR: you're using [Json refs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595377/json-schema-regarding-use-of-ref).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31725765/542251) seems to suggest that this isn't particularly well supported. [The document](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03) this is based on and is mentioned in that blog appears to be an expired draft.

Comment: Thanks for comfirming that this is not really well supported in general. I'll quote some of the project I'm linking to clearify.