# Properly de-marshall Angular FormGroup POST with linked objects

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-data-rest, angular2-forms

**TL;DR;**

In an Angular 2.x + Spring Data REST + Spring Boot 1.4 application, **how do you define JSON object references which Spring can de-marshall** into the domain model?

**Details**

For example, if a recipe book contains `labels` and `recipes` created at the same time and each `recipe` has a reference to one or more `labels`, the representation might look like:

```
book: {
  title: 'Cook book',
  labels:[{            <--- array index used in labelRef below
    name: 'fruit',
    description: 'Recipe with fruit.'
  },{
    name: 'vegetable',
    description: 'Recipe with vegetables.'
  },{
    name: 'fish',
    description: 'Recipe with fish.'
  }],
  recipes:[{
    title: 'Sweet corn and onion salad',
    description: 'Simple, quick, and refreshing corn salad',
    labels: [{
      labelRef: 1      <--- using array index as reference
    }]
  }]
}
```

where the array of `labelRef` using the array index in `labels` as client-side label identifiers (requiring array order to be guaranteed...). Since `labels` and `recipes` are POSTed at the same time, there are no persistent identifiers for either `label` or `recipe`. The Angular form for the recipe book is built dynamically so the user can add as many labels and recipes as desired:

```
    let book =     this._fb.group({
      title:       this._fb.control(''),
      labels:      this._fb.array([this.buildLabel()]),
      recipes:     this._fb.array([this.buildRecipe()])
    });

  buildLabel(): FormGroup {
    return         this._fb.group({
      name:        this._fb.control(''),
      description: this._fb.control('')
    });
  }

  buildRecipe(): FormGroup {
    return         this._fb.group({
      title:       this._fb.control(''),
      description: this._fb.control(''),
      labels:      this._fb.array([])
    });
  }

  buildLabelReference(index: number): FormGroup {
    return         this._fb.group({
      labelIndex:  this._fb.control(index)
    });
  }
```

The mid-tier representation in Spring Data JPA + Lombok **`Label`**:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "LABEL")
public class Label {    
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String name = "";
    private String description = "";

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="book_id")
    private Book book;
}
```

**`Recipe`**:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "RECIPE")
public class Recipe {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String title = "";
    private String description = "";

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="book", orphanRemoval=true)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private List<Label> labels = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="book_id")
    private Book book;
}
```

**`Book`**:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String title = "";

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="book", orphanRemoval=true)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Set<Label> labels = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="book", orphanRemoval=true)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private List<Recipe> recipes = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

The `Book` is properly de-marhalled in the `@RepositoryRestController`:

```
@Slf4j
@RepositoryRestController
public class BookRespositoryRestController {

    private final BookRepository bookRepository;
    private final LabelRepository labelRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/books")
    public @ResponseBody PersistentEntityResource post(@RequestBody Book book,
            PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {

        Book entity = processPost(book);

        return assembler.toResource(entity);
    }
```

**except** for recipe's labels (since `labelRef` is unknown to the domain model).

So, how do I construct a proper `labelRef` in my Angular TypeScript application so the `Book` is also de-marshals the `label` links in each `recipe` object?

Comment: Trying to convert the JSON object directly to the persistence entity is probably not a good idea; why not introduce a middle tier that knows how to convert one to the other?

Comment: By design, Spring Data REST does most of that work, @jonrsharpe, (though I do have to patch-up some object references in `processPost` for the entities to save correctly). I could create a `BookJson` Java object which has the `labelRef` array and patch-up that way but it seems like SDR's intent is to be able to do if it's encoded properly on the Angular forms side...but perhaps that's asking too much?

Comment: The only way I could see to do this would be to either  use a custom Jackson deserializer or split the POST into two requests i.e. One to save the initial book + labels. You then post the recipes with the correct links to the already existing labels. http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_adding_custom_de_serializers_to_jackson_s_objectmapper

Comment: @AlanHay -- splitting it into two requests works in my example but I can't do that in my model which motivated the question. I'll write-up an answer shortly for the solution I implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

It's not supported (yet), unfortunately. But you can add support with a bit of custom code.

### Details

There are two fundamental problems that need to be solved: define a JSON object reference; and, encode client-side JSON object references and decode server-side JSON object references.

#### References to JSON objects

There are a number of proposals for "standard" JSON references (see "[Standard way of referencing an object by identity (for, eg, circular references)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001474/json-standard-way-of-referencing-an-object-by-identity-for-eg-circular-refer)" for example) but as of 2017 there is no "standard".

#### Multiple requests

If you can split the requests, submit the referenced objects first and then use unique relative server-side paths as references to objects:

```
  /labels/1: {
    name: 'fruit',
    description: 'Recipe with fruit.'
  }

  /labels/2: {
    name: 'vegetable',
    description: 'Recipe with vegetables.'
  }

  /labels/3: {
    name: 'fish',
    description: 'Recipe with fish.'
  }
```

and the second request then uses the server-side paths:

```
  recipes:[{
    title: 'Sweet corn and onion salad',
    description: 'Simple, quick, and refreshing corn salad',
    labels: [{
      label: '/labels/1'
    }]
  }]
```

Spring Data REST supports this model without any custom code (although you likely will have to patch-up any bi-directional pointers in a more complex model).

#### Single request

If you need to use a single request, choose a JSON object reference model and encode your references accordingly. On the server-side, de-marshall/de-serialize the data using custom code.

Spring Data REST supports [adding custom (de)serializers to Jackson's ObjectMapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_adding_custom_de_serializers_to_jackson_s_objectmapper). Alternatively, a data transfer object can do the de-marhalling.

I used JSONPath and added a de-serializer to a data transfer object on the server side:

```
book: {
  title: 'Cook book',
  labels:[{
    name: 'fruit',
    description: 'Recipe with fruit.'
  },{
    name: 'vegetable',
    description: 'Recipe with vegetables.'
  },{
    name: 'fish',
    description: 'Recipe with fish.'
  }],
  recipes:[{
    title: 'Sweet corn and onion salad',
    description: 'Simple, quick, and refreshing corn salad',
    labels: [{
      label: '$..labels[1]'      <--- using JSONPath reference
    }]
  }]
}
```